# Unable to get current route instance in observers

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am now with ember js. I need current route instance in controllers observer. I tried many links and searched a lot but still not able to get the route instance in observer method. 
There is the code.

```
activeStagesChanged: Ember.observer('activeStages.[]', function () {
    let self = this;

    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', function () {
      initCustomScrollbar('#status_timeline_box');

      self.handleAppStages(self.get('model'), self.get('currentUser.isConfirmAppStageChange'),
          Ember.getOwner(self).lookup('controller:application'));
    });
  })
```

Ember.getOwner(self).lookup('controller:application') this is the code that I assuming to return the route object.

Comment: It would be good to know the reason or use case behind accessing route instance in  observers, because there might be some other alternatives to your use case.

Comment: this is ruby on rails application and we are using ember as front end technology. i am sending this route to a callback written is simple js to refresh route on some action.

Answer (score 1):

You can define actions `refreshFromCont` in route file,

```
actions:{
 refreshFromCont(){
  this.refresh();
 }
}
```

From inside controllers observer you can call `this.send('refreshFromCont')` It will call the current controllers route and parent route and in order.

Comment: This is working. I am returning this from action. is it write approach?

Comment: @wasipeer Yes it is afaik. maybe you can unmark this answer until some others will chime in provide their valuable feedback or different approach/answer.